# Azure WebApps and CosmosDB in the Germany Central Region not showing

Tags: azure

Azure Germany Central shows that WebApps and CosmosDB are available in the Azure Germany Central region, but they're not showing in the Webplans or the individual items.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which portal are you logging in? Azure Germany has a separate portal - https://portal.microsoftazure.de.

Answer (score 3):

MCD (Microsoft Cloud Deutschland) is a completely **separated** cloud thats why you won't be able to see it at portal.azure.com, you may want to start here:

https://portal.microsoftazure.de

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Cloud Deutschland does not exist any more, because Microsoft now has new Data Centers in Germany. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/germany/germany-migration-main)

According to Microsoft, the Availability Zone "Germany West Central" (GermanyWestCentral) supports CosmosDb. Though I do not see it offered in the portal yet (May 2022).
See
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies
and
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/services/?regions=germany-west-central,non-regional&products=cosmos-db